# Obtain an exact expression for the heat capacity of the system

Tags: thermodynamics

Before anyone mentions it, yes I did my research and found [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16762/calculating-the-heat-capacity-of-a-system) on this site. My question is his exact question, but I'd like some clarification or maybe a bit more explanation than the one given. I don't quite understand the first part he (the person who answered correctly) mentioned about $P(1)$.

The question: A system consists of N weakly interacting subsystems. Each system possesses only 2 energies, $E_1$ and $E_2$, each of them non-degenerate. Obtain an exact expression for the heat capacity of the system.

This was my attempt:

If $$C=\frac{\partial \bar E}{\partial T}$$

And if $$\bar E = \frac{E_1+E_2}{2}$$

Then $$C=\frac{\partial (N(\frac{E_1+E_2}{2}))}{\partial T}$$

---

**Update:** I made another go at it based on some help given in the comments.

$$P(1) = \frac{e^{-\frac{E_1}{kT}}}{e^{-\frac{E_1}{kT}}+e^{-\frac{E_2}{kT}}}$$
$$P(2) = \frac{e^{-\frac{E_2}{kT}}}{e^{-\frac{E_1}{kT}}+e^{-\frac{E_2}{kT}}}$$
$$\bar E = N(P_1E_1+P_2E_2)$$

Now, based on the hint at the back of the book (Statistical Physics by F. Mandl), I see that we can assume $E_1$ to be zero (not sure why though, is it because $E_1$ and $E_2$ are arbitrary?). My reasoning leads to me say this:

$$\frac{E_2Ne^{-\frac{E_2}{kT}}}{{1+e^{-\frac{E_2}{kT}}}}$$

*However,* the hint in the back of the book goes on to state what appears to be the final value of $\bar E$(again, shooting for understanding here and to help others understand this concept) as:

$$\bar E = \frac{NE_2}{e^{-\frac{E_2}{kT}}}$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: hint: $P(i)\propto \mathrm e^{-\beta E_i}$ is the probability that the system has energy $E_i$. Therefore, $\bar E=P(1)E_1+P(2)E_2$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  why do we need to bring probability into this though? It sounds like a silly question, I know, but the problem does say that the system has energy...

Comment: statical physics **is** probabilities. Anyway, what is your question exactly? How to calculate the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial T}(E_1+E_2)$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Good point, sorry I'm new to this. Was my reasoning on the right track though? If so then yes, I need help differentiating. If not, I want to understand why.

Comment: Its fine. Your reasoning was on the right track, but your expression for $\bar E$ is wrong. The mean energy is not the arithmetic mean of the energies, but the weighted mean, where the weight is given by the [Boltzmann factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) $\mathrm e^{-\beta E}$. This is the most important relation of statical mechanics (if you are not familiar with it, you should grab a book on statical mechanics)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Ok I worked this problem a bit more and updated the question, could you help me out a bit more?